# no matching function for call to 'MyLinSearch::AddEnumerator(MySeqInFileEnumerator*)'|

Tags: c++

*EDITED*Thanks for the previous helps.Got this problem now, doesnt like the pr.AddEnumerator(&t); line of the code.But its the same like in the sample task.
The AddEnumerator() is a method in procedure.hpp :

```
void AddEnumerator(Enumerator<Item>* en){ enor = en;}.
```

Procedure is the base class.
Also in seqinfileenumerator.hpp:

```
class SeqInFileEnumerator : public Enumerator<Item>
```

and in linsearch.hpp:

```
class LinSearch : public Procedure<Item>



#include <iostream>
#include "linsearch.hpp"
#include "seqinfileenumerator.hpp"

using namespace std;

struct MyPair
{
    int azon;
    int osszeg;
    friend ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& f, MyPair& df);
};


ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& f, MyPair& df)
{

    f >> df.azon >> df.osszeg;
    return f;
}


  class MyLinSearch: public LinSearch <int, true>
    {
        bool Cond(const int& e) const
        {
            return e<=-100000;
        }
    };


    class MySeqInFileEnumerator: public SeqInFileEnumerator <MyPair>
    {

        public:
        MySeqInFileEnumerator(char const * p) : SeqInFileEnumerator<MyPair>(p) { }
        void Next()
            {
                MyPair dx;
                f >> dx;
                df.azon=dx.azon;
                df.osszeg=dx.osszeg;
                while(dx.azon==df.azon)
                {
                    dx.osszeg+=df.osszeg;
                    f >> dx;
                }
            }
    };



int main()
{


    MyLinSearch pr;
    MySeqInFileEnumerator file_enum("input.txt");
    pr.AddEnumerator(&file_enum);
    pr.Run();

    if (pr.Found())
    {
        cout << "false " << endl;

    }
    else cout << "true" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `AddEnumerator` a member of `LinSearch` (or a public base class thereof)? Does `SeqInFileEnumerator` derive (publicly) from `Enumerator`? It's hard to guess what might be wrong with the headers you haven't shown us.

Comment: AddEnumerator isnt the member of LinSearch, its a method of Procedure, whitch is the base class.And class SeqInFileEnumerator : public Enumerator<Item>

Comment: It looks like you need the same template argument for both your Search and Enumerator classes, but you have `int` for one and `MyPair` for the other. Although it's hard to be sure from these small fragments of code.

Comment: yes, sorry I just didnt wanted to copy all of the headers i have for this work.

Comment: Yeah I changed class MyLinSearch: public LinSearch <int, true> to class MyLinSearch: public LinSearch <MyPair> and so on, and its working, so thanks for all your help.